# dont know to create a linked list

Tags: c

I am trying to make linked list, but I am not able to do this.When I try to print it out, It still prints just first node. I know it means the first one has no reference to next one.
I would be glad if someone helped me.

Here is the code:

```
struct book {
char *author;
char *title;
int year;
struct book *next;
};

struct book *insert_books() {
char c,x;
int i=0;    
struct book *first=(struct book*)malloc(sizeof(struct book));

struct book *current=(struct book*)malloc(sizeof(struct book));

struct book *new=(struct book*)malloc(sizeof(struct book));

first->author=(char*)malloc(30*sizeof(char));

first->title=(char*)malloc(50*sizeof(char));

first->next=NULL;

i=0;
scanf("%d\n",&first->year);

c='a';

while(c!='\n') {
    c=getchar();
    first->author[i]=c; 
    i++;
        }

first->author[i]='\0';
i=0;
c='a';

while(c!='\n') {
    c=getchar();
    first->title[i]=c; 
    i++;
        }

first->author[i]='\0';
current=first;
printf("\nWanna continue?(y/n)");
scanf("%c",&x);     

while(x=='y') {
    new->author=(char*)malloc(30*sizeof(char));
    new->title=(char*)malloc(50*sizeof(char));
    new->next=NULL;
    i=0;
    scanf("%d\n",&new->year);
    c='a';

    while(c!='\n') {
        c=getchar();
        new->author[i]=c; 
        i++;
        }

    new->author[i]='\0';
    i=0;
    c='a';

    while(c!='\n') {
        c=getchar();
        new->title[i]=c; 
        i++;
        }

    new->author[i]='\0';
    current->next=new;
    current=current->next;
    printf("\nWanna continue?(y/n)");
    scanf("%c",&x); 

            } 
return first;

}
```

Comment: All these malloc() and not a single free() hurt me.

Comment: I have a void for freeing this linked list

Comment: When you insert a node into the list, you should create only one `struct book` with `malloc`, namely the struct holding the new book. All other pointers either point to instances of existing nodes or should be `NULL`. I see that often with linked list; I guess, people are taught not to access pointers without allocating memory, but in this case, it's plain wrong.

Comment: Also, the code will be much clearer if you separate all the input stuff from the actual logic of the linked list.

Comment: So I have to allocate only new, even if the function has to return refference to first node?So the first doesnt have to be allocated? And sorry for this mess caused by input stuff in the code.

Answer (score 0):

You are appending the `next` pointer value of `current` to itself. So when you call the next `book` of `current`, it is still `current`. Moreover, you should factorize your code and not have redundant process like

```
while(c!='\n') {
    c=getchar();
    first->author[i]=c; 
    i++;
        }
```

An finnaly, due to your copy/paste I think, you forgot to change `first->author[i]='\0';` to `first->title[i]='\0';`

Comment: And I think you have a lot of things to learn about before trying to implement linked lists.

Comment: And could you give me some advice how to append next pointer correctly in a loop to create linked list? I have already implemented  the same code for linked list in another function and it was right.  And thanks for your remind.Yes, it was due my copy/paste.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this use &(first->year) instead of &first->year and allocate memory to new again in if block.

```
struct book *insert_books() {
    char c,x;
    int i=0;    
    struct book *first=(struct book*)malloc(sizeof(struct book));

struct book *current=(struct book*)malloc(sizeof(struct book));

struct book *new=(struct book*)malloc(sizeof(struct book));

first->author=(char*)malloc(30*sizeof(char));

first->title=(char*)malloc(50*sizeof(char));

first->next=NULL;

i=0;
scanf("%d\n",&(first->year));

c='a';

while(c!='\n') {
    c=getchar();
    first->author[i]=c; 
    i++;
        }

first->author[i]='\0';
i=0;
c='a';

while(c!='\n') {
    c=getchar();
    first->title[i]=c; 
    i++;
        }

first->author[i]='\0';
current=first;
printf("\nWanna continue?(y/n)");
scanf("%c",&x);     

while(x=='y') {
            new=(struct book*)malloc(sizeof(struct book));
    new->author=(char*)malloc(30*sizeof(char));
    new->title=(char*)malloc(50*sizeof(char));
    new->next=NULL;
    i=0;
    scanf("%d\n",&new->year);
    c='a';

    while(c!='\n') {
        c=getchar();
        new->author[i]=c; 
        i++;
        }

    new->author[i]='\0';
    i=0;
    c='a';

    while(c!='\n') {
        c=getchar();
        new->title[i]=c; 
        i++;
        }

    new->author[i]='\0';
    current->next=new;
    current=current->next;
    printf("\nWanna continue?(y/n)");
    scanf("%c",&x); 

            } 
return first;

}
```